# How to sort dates below 1970 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sorting, date, momentjs

so I am sorting dates and there is one date of `1967-08-07`, what would be the correct approach to it?

The unix timestamp is negative and I haven't found any clues how to do in JS.

Comment: Nothing to do here. `1967-08-07 < 1970-01-01` is `true`.

Comment: So are you sorting the rest of dates by millisecond value ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

```
1967-08-07
```

structure is easy sortable as string, because it has the year as first part, followed by month and day.

Comment: Thanks! Tried to overcomplicate things

Answer (score 0):

If the dates are of different formats that are not easily compared, you could convert the dates to date objects and compare those:

```
// CREATE OBJECTS
var dateOne = new Date("October 16, 2017");
var dateTwo = new Date("1967-08-07");

// COMPARE
if(dateOne > dateTwo){

   // DO SOMETHING

}
```

Comment: Don't use the built-in parser. "1967-08-07" will be parsed as UTC, "October 16, 2017" as local (or NaN), so `new Date('1967-08-07') > new Date(1967,7,7)` is true.